# Xslt transforming error

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform my XML file using an XSLT and the error ' can't parse the data source (my XML path) Please fix it before transforming appears

Can anybody tell me what does this error mean, why does it appear And how can I fix it?

Thank you very much

My xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<videoclub>
<pelicula>
<titulo>pelicula1
</titulo>
<director>myself
</director>
<duracion>30 minutos
</duracion>
</pelicula>
<pelicula>
<titulo>pelicula2
</titulo>
<director>otrapersona
</director>
<duracion>20 minutos
</duracion>
</pelicula>
</videoclub>
```

And here is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- New XSLT document created with EditiX XML Editor (http://www.editix.com) at Thu Mar 15 12:10:43 CET 2018 -->

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
        <h2>pelculas
        </h2>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>titulo</th>
        <th>director</th>

        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="videoclub/pelicula">
        <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="titulo"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="director"/></td>
        </tr>



        </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You may be attempting to transform [**non-well-formed XML**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085), but if you want to receive good help here, provide a [mcve].  Thanks.

Comment: When I use your xml file and your xsl file as input of the program xsltproc, I get no error. ¿Qué pasa aquí?

Comment: Is it possible that this can be a problem of the editor that  i am using? because i am using editix XML editor

Comment: Does your XML have any spaces or new lines before the `<?xml ` declaration?

Comment: Were you able to solve this error?